# Journey Builder/Communities - Welcome Email - Registration URL

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, email-template, journeybuilder

We would like to utilise Journey Builder to send the Welcome Email to new community users with the registration link.  Salesforce provides this link in email templates via `{!Community_URL}` and via the global variable `$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails`.

What is required to access this URL via Marketing Cloud to send the welcome email via Journey Builder?  Is this even possible?

UPDATE: Found this blog post from 2014. It states that there is no way to generate this URL via APEX or other means:
https://lahirustechtalk.wordpress.com/2014/12/25/customize-community-welcome-email-including-community_url/

Seems that Salesforce requires the standard SF email templates or visualforce templates to allow new community users to register.  I am not seeing a way to bring this URL into a Journey Builder generated email.

UPDATE:  I'm sad about this.

Comment: Correct. This cannot be implemented. I have connected with SFDC support and checked with MVPs before I wrote this blog. You may write a separate trigger to send additional/required emails on new user creation event for a new communities. You can re-build the same look and feel from VF pages. Hope this helpful

Comment: Whereas the transactional email, i.e. welcome/confirmation email needs to be sent with the standard SF E-Mail template, you can still use the Connector to inject the people who signed up into an Onboarding Journey or such. Journey Builder is not built to send a single transactional message but a range of different messages over a period of time. So an Onboarding Journey based on the Community User Object could be an idea.